# GSdx10 plugin for PCSX2 1.4.0 not showing in config menu

Tags: pc, technical-issues, pcsx2

I downloaded the GSdx10 plugin for PCSX2 1.4.0 and placed in with the other GSdx plugins in "C:\Program Files (x86)\PCSX2 1.4.0\Plugins" folder. It is not showing in the configuration menu. How do I solve this?

Machine: Lenovo g50-80, 
Os: Win 10, 
CPU: i7-5500U,
RAM: 4Gb

Comment: There is the simple potential that they are not supported for Windows 10 yet. I would have to research this more when I get home to my setup.